# Выбор MQ очереди

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, activemq

Необходимо выбрать MQ очередь или что-то, что можно использовать таким образом, в рамках следующих условий.

1. Продюсеров и потребителей может быть десятки тысяч, при этом каждый из них свободно подключается и отключается. В моменты когда продюсер отключен от своего топика сообщения в нее просто не поступают, когда подключается - снова поступают. Когда потребитель подключается, то начинает получать сообщения с момента когда подключился (как `auto-offset-reset=latest` в Kafka)
2. Порядок сообщений критично важен.
3. Скорость доставки важна.
4. Гарантия доставки критично важна.
5. Новые продюсеры появляются постоянно и топики появляются вместе с ними. 1 продюсер = 1 топик.
6. Сообщения не большие, это строки до 200 символов.
7. Хранить их историю в хранилище очереди нет смысла так как они будут сохраняться в PostgreSQL. (Возможно какой-то in-memory вариант)
8. Каждый потребитель получает все сообщения самостоятельно (Выражаясь терминологией Kafka `group-id` у каждого свой)
9. Подключаемся из Java клиента.

Сценарии использования (все продюсеры и потребители десктопные клиенты)

1. Новый продюсер регистрируется в системе и под него создается топик\канал к которому можно подключатся.
2. Продюсер включает десктопный клиент и начинает раздачу сообщений. (Включается по кнопке начать трансляцию).
3. Некоторые из пользователей узнав о новом продюсере решают стать его подписчиками и подключается к нему используя десктопный клиент, и получив id топика, получают сообщения пока не нажмут кнопку отключения от трансляции.

Учитывая требования к скорости и и количеству подключений напрашивается Kafka, но она гарантирует упорядоченность только в рамках партиции что вызывает сомнения в гарантиях доставки. Остальные очереди типа RabbitMQ и ActiveMQ не удовлетворяют требованиям по кол-ву подключений.

Возможно единственный выход это использовать Kafka, контролируя, что бы на 1 топик была только 1 партиция, или может есть другие решения которых я не вижу?

Comment: Ну судя по сценарию использования, в частности п. 3, действительно нигде нет потребности в увеличении партиций на топик > 1. И не понял связи в "она гарантирует упорядоченность только в рамках партиции что вызывает сомнения в гарантиях доставки"

Comment: @asanisimov ну если я использую по 1 партицию для каждого топика что бы получать сообщения строго в том порядке в котором они были отправлены, то получится что данные хранятся только на одной ноде, или кафка реплицирует партиции по всем нодам кластера?

Comment: это зависит от ваших настроек, если доставка так критична то нужна репликация как минимум на 3 ноды(мб больше/меньше, все зависит от разных условий) и при записи сообщения подтверждение со всех нод (acks - all , если память не изменяет), что сделает запись синхронной, но даст гарантию что сообщение не потеряется при отказе лидера и перебалансировки нод.

Comment: Кстати, если память не изменяет, при нескольких партициях в топике если читает 1 консьюмер то сообщения все равно будут упорядоченны (но это не утверждение, я бы проверил), но в вашем случае вообще не вижу необходимости в увеличении партиций топика.

Comment: @asanisimov да, это так, но к сожалению - это не мой случай, так как одним  консьюмером дело точно не обойдется.

Comment: говоря консьюмер я подразумевал 1 консьюмер на 1 консьюмер_групп 1-го топика. нет смысла в параллельном чтении за счет партиций, если клиент подписывается на публикации и синхронно их читает

Comment: @asanisimov это да

Comment: Если будешь использовать Кафку, я советую потестировать **как можно раньше** конфигурацию с десятками тысяч топиков, потому что Кафка может не потянуть. Это старые сообщения, но всё равно проблема может быть не решена до сих пор (1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/52843013/998126 (2) https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/